# Is there a way to have BBEdit's "run in terminal" command use a different terminal emulator application?

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm, bbedit

I would prefer to use iTerm rather than the built-in OS X Terminal application. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

From the "Expert Preferences" webpage:
https://www.barebones.com/support/bbedit/ExpertPreferences.html

The "Run in Terminal" and "Go Here in Terminal" commands will use Apple's "Terminal" application by default. If you would like to use a different one:

```
defaults write com.barebones.bbedit TerminalBundleID -string "com.example.TerminalAppBundleID"
```

(Use the actual terminal's bundle ID in place of "com.example.TerminalAppBundleID"…)